# Easy way to convert dots into -> in QtCreator

Tags: pointers, structure, qt-creator

I assigned to a project written by someone else. They passed parameters as variables (I mean those things copied to stack when a method is called) and I like them to converted to pointers. It runs significantly faster because only 32-bit or 64-bit pointers are passed to the subroutines. I have almost 600 methods to be converted.

An example method is defined as:

```
bool insideWindow(tsPoint Point, tsWindow Window)
```

When I change the type tsWindow into psWindow (defined as *tsWindow) I need to change all dots (.) to (->) in order to imply a pointer operation.

Is there any easy way to change these in QtCreator? To put in another way, I want to change the type to a pointer type and QtCreator will easily change dots into -> ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is easily solved by passing variables as references. All I need to do is to modify the function prototype (both in h and in cpp files).

```
bool insideWindow(tsPoint &Point, tsWindow &Window)
```

This way it still needs a dot (means I won't change the code, replacing dots with -> operators) and they are passed as pointers in fact.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html